# how can i solve a problem with np.loadtxt

Tags: python, numpy, txt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OW0U.png)i tried to use np.loadtxt to read my data like below.
first, i made a txt file like

`f=open("C:/temp/house_data.txt","r") data=f.read() f.close() print(data)`

and it worked well i think.
but after i get this result, i write some code like

`import numpy as np house_data=np.loadtxt("C:/temp/house_data.txt")`

but the result says " could not convert string to float: 'array([[-6.,-7.,-2],'"
i want to know what is wrong with my code and how to get right array..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNCGW.png)

Comment: Is array present in the file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and congrats on your first question! Instead of posting your code as an image, please copy and paste it into your question.  If you need help with formatting it you can indent the code by selecting it after you paste it into the question box and pressing `Ctrl+K`.  The toolbar in the editor can also help you.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you produced `house_data.txt` but it looks like you or someone else wrote the literal string representation of a numpy ndarray object to a file.  I suspect something like this was done:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(20).reshape(10, 2)
>>> with open('house_data.txt', 'w') as f:
...     f.write(repr(a))
... 
>>> print(open('house_data.txt').read())
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11],
       [12, 13],
       [14, 15],
       [16, 17],
       [18, 19]])
```

If you want a simple way to save a Numpy array as a plain text file, just as there is `np.loadtxt` there is also `np.savetxt`:

```py
>>> np.savetxt('house_data.txt', a)
>>> print(open('house_data.txt').read())
0.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+01 1.100000000000000000e+01
1.200000000000000000e+01 1.300000000000000000e+01
1.400000000000000000e+01 1.500000000000000000e+01
1.600000000000000000e+01 1.700000000000000000e+01
1.800000000000000000e+01 1.900000000000000000e+01
>>> np.loadtxt('house_data.txt')
array([[  0.,   1.],
       [  2.,   3.],
       [  4.,   5.],
       [  6.,   7.],
       [  8.,   9.],
       [ 10.,  11.],
       [ 12.,  13.],
       [ 14.,  15.],
       [ 16.,  17.],
       [ 18.,  19.]])
```